# ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 45, 17)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I have a complex def function on local Spyder and meeting problem. I have tried it in Colab and it worked.

My code error message shows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File ~/Downloads/New-S-1/companyData/untitled3.py:76 in 
> dfList=pd.DataFrame(dfList)

> File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:737 in **init**
> mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(

> File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:331 in ndarray_to_mgr
> values = _prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy_on_sanitize)

> File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:591 in _prep_ndarray
> raise ValueError(f"Must pass 2-d input. shape={values.shape}")

> ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 45, 17)

I have see a lot of material but cannot figure my situation. how to automatically detect the multi-index things and change it to compatible format? I would be very grateful if you can give me any suggestion!!

```
import pandas as pd 
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import reader
import csv
import time

urls=['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1021096/0001477932-21-001813.txt', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1021604/0001213900-21-019274.txt', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1022899/0001493152-21-003410.txt']
Indexs =['39', '40','41']


def download(url):
  global dfd
  def OperationsNumber(word):
    if len(x_list) ==0:
      if dfs[x].apply(lambda x: x.apply(str).str.isnumeric().sum().sum() >1).any() and (dfs[x].iloc[:, 0]==word).any() :
        x_list.append(x)
    else: 
        return None
    return x_list

  headers = {'User-Agent': 'registr@jh.edu'}
  response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
  response.raise_for_status()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
  x_list=[]
  dfs=[]
  dfList=[]
  try:
    for table in soup.find_all('table'):
      dfs.extend(pd.read_html(table.prettify()))  
  except: 
    pass
  
  for x in range(len(dfs)):
    OperationsNumber('Accumulated Deficit')
    OperationsNumber('Accumulated deficit')
    OperationsNumber('Accumulated  Deficit')
    OperationsNumber('Accumulated  deficit')
    OperationsNumber('ACCUMULATED  DEFICIT')

  for x in x_list:
    dfd=dfs[x]
    dfList.append(dfd)
    #return (dfs)
  return dfList

for url,Index in zip(urls,Indexs):
    dfList=download(url)
    dfList=pd.DataFrame(dfList)#this table dfList does not fit DataFrame?
    dfList.to_csv('/Users/GO/Downloads/New-S-1/{Index}-try3.csv')
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) In this case ,this should also include some copy-paste -able data for `dfs`

Comment: Thanks for reminding ! I have updated the definition for dfs, which is a list contains a lot of tables. Making dfs[x] is to find the specific table to display.

Comment: This code is ill-formatted (e.g. the `return dfd` looks wrongly indented) and is also not runnable (for example, the `urls` variable is not defined). Please reduce your code as much as possible such that it is still producing your error, but keep it runable

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions! I have tried to correct most of them and still find errors on transform the table to dataframe. I have also studied this issue for a long time and cannot get the solution. Do you have any idea?